# Randomly choosing a % of elements in a string and changing the value

Tags: python

I have a sting and need to randomly replace 5% of the elements, and flip them to 0 if they are 1, and flip them to 1 if they are 0.

I have a string that looks like this:

```
'10011110110001000111010011010100101100100110111000010001111100001010000011101100011110100110001110010101010000100111000101001100100110110010010100000010111110000011001001011011010111111010001011101011110100000101010110100001001011010000111110101011001101011000100100010010100011100001011011110001010101010101100001111111010101000010011010010110111100011111001011100101001000101011110000010111101111101100010010010011011101101110110000000000101010101010101011111011010111000101010010001010110011101011'
```

Effectively, 5% of the values in the string will change from a 0 to 1, or vice versa.

I have tried this but it does not seem to work, and isn't guaranteed to only replace 5% of the elements:

```
for i in range(500):
    if random.random() < 0.05:
        if test[i] == '1':
            test[i] == '0'
        else:
            test[i] == '1'
```

Comment: Strings are immutable so you'll need it split into a list or similar

Comment: Are you open to use numpy or do you want to stay with random library?

Comment: There is no reason for `if random.random() < 0.05:`, the number of samples is deterministic, you only need to know what the indices to change are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work on Python 2.7 and 3.6 (tested; probably newer as well).

```
import random
sting = '10011110110001000111010011010100101100100110111000010001111100001010000011101100011110100110001110010101010000100111000101001100100110110010010100000010111110000011001001011011010111111010001011101011110100000101010110100001001011010000111110101011001101011000100100010010100011100001011011110001010101010101100001111111010101000010011010010110111100011111001011100101001000101011110000010111101111101100010010010011011101101110110000000000101010101010101011111011010111000101010010001010110011101011'
sting = ''.join([chr(ord(y) ^ 1) if x in random.sample(range(len(sting)),len(sting)//20) else y for x,y in enumerate(list(sting))])
print (sting)
```

I have tried this and it works, and is guaranteed to only replace 5% of the elements.

It toggles exactly 5% -- the length of `sting` divided by 20, which is 5% -- characters from `0` to `1` and from `1` to `0`, without duplicates. Toggling is done with [XOR](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html) operator and [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=random%20sample#random.sample) picks indices to replace "unique elements", i.e. without duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change two things

1. strings are immutable. So, `test = list(test)` before your loop, and `test = ''.join(test)` after it
2. Choose in advance which elements you want to change

First, choose `n` random indexes. One option is using `random.choice` *without* replacement

```
 num_elements = int(0.05 * len(test))
 indexes = random.choice(list(range(len(test)), num_elements, replace=False)
```

and then modify the values as before.